# Sqoop Statements without quotes

Tags: sql, hadoop, jdbc, teradata, sqoop

I use sqoop to query data from teradata to hadoop. The problem is that the table is to big to query at once. So I need to split the jobs into seperate tasks.

```
sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:teradata://td.xxxxxx.com/database=db 
--as-textfile 
--table ref_product 
--target-dir /td_import/sqoop_import
--delete-target-dir
--username DB
--password secret 
--split-by "CAST(HASHBUCKET(hashrow(product_id) (BYTE(4))) AS BIGINT)" 
--columns 'product_id' 
--hive-import 
--num-mappers 200
```

The product_id itself is not well distribute but with the hashing and the hashbuckets. So what Sqoop does:

*1. Querying Min and Max:*

```
SELECT MIN( CAST(HASHBUCKET(hashrow('product_id') (BYTE(4))) AS BIGINT) ), 
MAX( CAST(HASHBUCKET(hashrow('product_id') (BYTE(4))) AS BIGINT) ) 
FROM "ref_product"
```

This works fine.

*2. Querying for first bucket:*

```
SELECT "product_id"
FROM "ref_product"
WHERE "CAST(HASHBUCKET(hashrow(product_id) (BYTE(4))) AS BIGINT)" >=0
AND "CAST(HASHBUCKET(hashrow(product_id) (BYTE(4))) AS BIGINT)" < 100
```

Crashes, and its clear why: 
It crashes because of the quotes at the beginning and at the end of the WHERE-attribute. The Query would even work if none of these quotes would be there.

**So my Question is: How can I force sqoop to not decorate the query with quotes?**

Kind regards
Hans

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop is expecting column name in --split-by and hence it's not designed to be given expression. Couple of ideas/questions that came to my mind:

1) Why is the table big enough to not be queried once? I've seen terabytes offloaded from teradata with Sqoop without any problem. What is the exception or issue that you're observing?

2) You can take advantage of --where that accepts arbitrary expression to "partition" the data.

Comment: 1. The table is indeed big enough to not be queried at once. I just have 100GB spooling space to do my queries. I cant even ask the database for a whole month.
2. Yes, I know the --where expression. But I want the whole table, not a part of it. And I cant use the attribute itself because its not well distributed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using boundary-query parameter as mentioned below:

sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:teradata://td.xxxxxx.com/database=db 
--as-textfile 
--table ref_product 
--target-dir /td_import/sqoop_import
--delete-target-dir
--username DB
--password secret 
**--split-by "CAST(product_id AS BIGINT) mod 200"**
**--boundary-query "SELECT 0,199"** 
--columns 'product_id' 
--hive-import 
--num-mappers 200

FYI: I was able to import around 1.5 + TB of data with 250+ columns.